# The best method to find a small group of numbers in a large group

Tags: c, math, random, numbers, probability

I am very far from mathematics, but would like to have an advice from knowledgeable people.

Imagine a large group of numbers from 1 to 1 exabyte.
Within this group, we have to find a small hidden group of 1000 numbers (with no gaps) with a starting point from 1 petabyte let's say.
I understand that the group is large and probably there is no way to find coordinates of this small group.
But..
How do I need to try to scan a large group to get at least once a single number from a small group?
It's clear to me that the random number test is the worst way.
Remains another option.
Take 1 exabyte and to divide this number each time incrementally and to test a groupe of coordinates each time:

- 1 exabyte / 3 -> we will have 3 coordinates to test by adding the result to 1
  each time.
- 1 exabyte / 4 -> we will have 4 coordinates to test by adding the result
  to 1 each time.
- ....

Is there a better way?
May be a Pseudo code or a code in C?

P.S. I can not explain the problem in detail.
I have not mentioned yet that I can increase the size of a small group. From 1000 to 1000000 (ex.) but it's more difficult to calculate for a computer. And with your help: a random solution + increase the small group seems to be a good choice now.
 **Thank you all for your ideas!**

Comment: If the values are sorted, I feel you might try to use Binary Search. Are you looking for specific values?

Comment: Yes, I am interested in the numbers within a small group. If at least once one of my test coordinates fall into any number in a small group -  I'll immediately know that I found this group.

Comment: Is the "small" group your are looking for guaranteed to be available in the "large" group? And your question is just about where it is?

Comment: This sounds like it is a string search, where the alphabet is the numbers. If so, [string searching algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) are well known. Unless the “small group” of numbers is a set, not a sequence.

Comment: Yes, I would like to know - Where is this group?! And yes - for sure, the small group is inside. And no, it's not a string search - only huge numbers.

Comment: @user3306780: The abstract definition of a string search is essentially that you are looking for one sequence inside another sequence. Looking for a sequence of numbers inside a another sequence of numbers is a string search. Unfortunately, you have not defined the problem well. What is a “group” of numbers? Is it a set? A sequence? If you are looking for 3, 4, and 5 in a large “group” of numbers and you find 5, 3, and 4, does that constitute a solution (because you found them, in a different order)? If you find 3, 4, 7, and 5, is that a solution (because you found them, not consecutively)?

Comment: @EricPostpischil As I understand it, OP is finding a specific subset of a large set of numbers. E.g. find `{3,1,5}` in `{0,5,2,3,6,8,...,89,3,1,5,9}`. I made the assumption in my answer it is unordered, and I'm taking the lack of correction as confirmation of that..

Answer (score 0):

**You don't mention if sorted or not, so for either case:**

- Check every `n`th, where `n = 1000` or whatever size of the 'small hidden group'.
- When found, check either side (any amount to the side in range `[1, n]`).
- If correct, check rest of range until fail.
- If incorrect (at any point), check the other side.
- If other side incorrect, check the next `n`th

e.g. pseudo:

```
for i in range(0,N/n){
    if i in small_set{
        left_limit = test(i, left)
        right_limit = test(i, right)
        if (right_limit - left_limit == n) return left_limit
    }
}

def test(position, direction)
    move = 1
    if (direction == left) move = move *-1
    while (position in small_set) position += move
    return position
```

I do **not** claim this is the *most* efficient, but it is certainly simple, and the most efficient I can think of quickly.

Furthermore, you are incorrect in saying:

> ...the random number test is the worst way

On average, I believe the least efficient method would be a sequential test. If the first number is not in the group, then it is totally pointless checking the next `n-1`.

**If it is an ordered set and the small group are consecutive** then we can do exactly the same as the above, except no need to check the whole range, just `i` and `i + n - 1`, where `i` is the position of the first element from smaller set in the larger set.

Comment: Thank you. But to "Check every nth, where n = 1000 or whatever size of the 'small hidden group" is not a suitable solution - very time consuming.

Comment: If the large set is unordered you really don't have a lot of choice! It's exactly `n` times better than testing sequentially.

Comment: @user3306780: If there is no known ordering of the *N* numbers being searched, then it is logically impossible for a search for a sequence of *n* numbers to take fewer than *N* / *n* checks in the worst case. If you do not perform at least *N* / *n* checks, then there will be subsequences of least *n* numbers in the complete sequence in which no number is checked, and then the subsequence could contain all the target numbers but the algorithm would have no knowledge of this.

Comment: Just confirm one thing. Am I right to think that 1000 numbers it's more easy to find when it's inside a group (with no gaps) and not 1000 numbers simply randomly installed in a large space.

Comment: @user3306780: Yes, the work required to find a group of numbers that must be together is easier than the work required to find numbers that might be scattered arbitrarily.

Comment: Of course it is, that's clear from the method above. You find one, and then count onwards/backwards from it. If they're not grouped, then you're finding each one separately, effectively the algorithm above but with `n=1`.

Comment: I can not explain the problem in detail. I have not mentioned yet that I can increase the size of a small group. From 1000 to 1000000 (ex.). And with your help a random solution + increase the small group seems to be a good choice now. Thank you all.

Comment: Generally you can expect better answers if you actually tell us all the criteria.. ;)

Comment: That said, the method I posted works fine with an increase in the small group. Just make `n` variable.

Comment: Thanks Ollie, i'll try to analize your idea in details.

Comment: @user3306780 no worries :) let me know if I can be of any further help.